# Event handler not working after moving element on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I am new to web programming and currently building a responsive website. On window resize event, the right sideBar moves by insertBefore() and appentTo() methods. But after that, the event handler on the sideBar does not work anymore.

A simple event handler method:

```
$('#sideBar').mouseover(function(){
  alert("hello");
});
```

works only if I remove:

```
function setlayout(){
  if($(window).width() <= 720){
    $('#sideBar').insertBefore('#footer');
  }else{
    $('#sideBar').remove().appendTo('#navbar');
  }
};
$(window).on('resize load', function(){  setlayout() });
```

How do I make the event handler work?

Comment: You learned me that it is possible to append an element to an element *after* removing it from the DOM, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As your sidebar is removed and then **dynamically** added to the page, you have to select it this way:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '#sideBar', function() {
    alert('hello');
});
```

jQuery attaches the events on load so if you remove the element from the page, all the event handlers attached to it are removed. That's why you have to **delegate** the events by calling them on the `$(document)` element.

Working [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Hulothe/uoc3yspr/).

Comment: I edited my answer, I had forgotten the capital letter in "side**B**ar" and I added a JSFiddle example.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#sideBar').appendTo('#navbar').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you remove a node, the handler of this node would remove, too.
So you should rebind event, or just use event delegate.
The way of @Hulothe is event delegate.

```
 $(document).on('mouseover', '#sideBar', function() {
    alert('hello');
});
```